# How to run view.py file in Django in order to scrape and store data

Tags: python, django, selenium, pycharm

I want to open and run a Django project in Pycharm. The project is about scrape data from another website by using beautiful soup and selenium and store data in a django database and show them on our own website. In order to launch the scraping process when I run `view.py` file, I encounter the following error.

```
File "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXXX\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Can you please help me to figure out the issue? I've struggled too much to solve the problem but could not solve that. I need to accomplish my task in a very limited time. I would be very grateful if anyone can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is a an external script to run Django and interact with the Django ORM.  This file would generally be in the same folder as manage.py.

external_script.py

```
import os
import django
    
# Project name settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.settings'

# Django setup will import all the necessary config from the setting file
django.setup()

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

from YOUR_APP.models import MODEL

print(MODEL.objects.all())
```